# Firebase flutter push notification not working on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing a fluter application where I have set up the APN key and uploaded the certificate to the firebase console and following is the code in my AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

  let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
    options: authOptions,
    completionHandler: { _, _ in }
  )
} else {
  let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
    UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
  application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

  override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

   Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
   super.application(application, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
 }
}
```

When I am sending the notification from the firebase console, it displays in my android application but it does not show in my iOS application. Which step am I missing here?

Comment: Did you test on a real device? Notifications don't work on iOS simulator.

Comment: yes, I did on real device also, the notification is not appearing

Comment: Did you add the .plist of the firebase configuration to your project?